# How do I initialize a variable given by an "if then" statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple code to play Rock, Paper, Scizzors, there is more to the code however this is the important part

```
    int comResult = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    String comChoice;
    if (comResult == 0) {
        comChoice = "rock";
    } else if (comResult == 1) {
        comChoice = "scizzors";
    } else if (comResult == 2) {
        comChoice = "paper";
    }

    String results;
    if (comChoice == humanChoice)
```

When I get to comparing the computers choice to the humans the computer says that I haven't declared a value for comChoice even though I put it in the if then statement, how do I properly declare the value

Comment: If `comResult` isn't 1, 2 or 3, what will `comChoice` be?

Comment: Java does not permit referencing uninitialized values, set comChoice to null.  Additionally your string comparison is a reference comparison, not a value comparison.

Comment: @awiebe It's rarely a good idea to ignore compiler errors by changing something to a value that it doesn't make sense for it to be (the computer isn't going to actually choose `null`). Instead, the `if`-`else` blocks should use an `else` for the final block instead of an `else if`. This guarantees that the variable is set properly for what follows, which is what the compiler error is about in the first place.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Your right, it should throw in the else state, because the program would have entered an illegal state, and dying in an invalid state is much better than proceeding in an unknown state. That being said I assumed given the quality of the code that the error handling was less important to the student at present than it is that the code run.  It looks like they probably haven't covered exceptions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an "else" at the end of your condition block to make sure comChoice gets initialized.

```
if (comResult == 0) {
    comChoice = "rock";
} else if (comResult == 1) {
    comChoice = "scizzors";
} else if (comResult == 2) {
    comChoice = "paper";
} else {
    comChoice = "invalid input";
}
```

Comment: Since `comChoice` stands for the computer's choice, the computer isn't likely to actually be inputting anything. An alternative is just to replace `else if (comResult == 2)` with `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch with default case.

Comment: ...provided that in that `default` case you assign `comResul` a value... The whole issue is that there is a point where the value of of `comResult` is needed, but there is a path through the program to that point along which `comResult` never got assigned a value.